# How can I create custom "Group Validation" with Bootstrap Validation?

Tags: jquery, css, validation, twitter-bootstrap

I was looking at [this tutorial](http://reactiveraven.github.io/jqBootstrapValidation/) on bootstrap validation. In the tutorial the email text controls are linked together by:

```
data-validation-matches-match="email"
```

Also with the group of checkboxes there is a `min` and `max` checked value.
My question is this, lets say I have a group of text boxes, in this example I have named the master div `AddressCityCounty`:

```
<div id="AddressCityCounty" style="width:800px;">
<div class="control-group" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
    <label class="control-label">Address:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqAddress" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtAddress" CssClass="required" EnableClientScript="true" Display="dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="*"/>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddress" runat="server" required/>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group" style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">
    <label class="control-label">City:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqCity" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCity" CssClass="required" EnableClientScript="true" Display="dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="*"/>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" required/>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="control-group" style="float:left;">
    <label class="control-label">County: 
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqCounty" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCounty" CssClass="required" EnableClientScript="true" Display="dynamic" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="*"/>
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCounty" runat="server" required/>
        <p class="help-block"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I go about scripting it so that the group of controls turn yellow (just like the email and Quality Control group from the tutorial) until all fields in this group have been filled out?

Comment: I wonder why bootstrap would need its own [validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)?

Comment: @Blazemonger bells and whistles are always nice...

Comment: @Blazemonger also my .net validation is already doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first and foremost I would recommend you not use asp.net controls to do this. I have used these in the past with twitter bootstrap with varying degrees of success. I would instead use HTML text boxes. If you are working with the .NET framework and you need server side validation might I also suggest .NET MVC with Model validation - a lot more cleaner.

First off you will need to add the jsBootstrapValidation to your project along with references to twitter bootstrap. After which you want to go ahead and follow the recommendations on the site. If you notice all you need for the email validation is for you to set your text box as

```
<input type="email" />
```

The jsBootstrapValidation will do the rest. But again - you won't be able to achieve this using asp.net controls.

You should be able to setup your asp.net controls as

```
<asp:Textbox id"emailTextbox" class="email" runat="server" />
```

After which you would need to provide custom jquery to handle the different events on say any text box with a certain class and do it that way. Cumbersome? Absolutely. Worth it? Depends on if this is a public facing app how anal are they about wanting stuff like this.

Comment: I am not using it for validation at all. I am using the jquery and the css to get the cool colors and glow when a user is filling out the form for a better user experience. I have tested the application that I am placing it on and it works just the same as it had before I added any of it. So by everyone's comment I am guessing that this functionality is not possible?

Comment: Ah, my bad  - it is possible just not with that particular library. I think you would have to modify it to work. The main issue is that once you render your asp.net webform you are always going to end up with a <input type="textbox" /> and that is clearly going off the type of email. If you write your own perhaps you can set it to go off certain classes for instance a class of email - so on and so forth.